# How to add multiple checkbox elements to media attachments?

Tags: attachments, options, forms, post-editor, customization

Based on solved question from:
[How to add a checkbox element to attachments editor with example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/how-to-add-a-checkbox-element-to-attachments-editor-with-example)

Theres an example of multiple Checkboxes, for example: Colors, patterns, etc... A grouped list but using checkboxes?

Tips to save and remember checked options on edit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same thing , just add as many checkboxes as you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Bainternet said, it is the same thing. Taking the code from the question you linked to, you can do it like this:

```
function filter_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $foo = (bool)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'foo', true );
    $bar = (bool)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bar', true );

    $form_fields['foo'] = array(
    'label' => 'Is Foo',
    'input' => 'html',
    'html' => '<label for="attachments-' . $post->ID . '-foo"> '.
        '<input type="checkbox" id="attachments-' . $post->ID . '-foo" name="attachments[' . $post->ID . '][foo]" value="1"' . ( $foo ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ) . ' /> Yes</label>  ',
    'value' => $foo,
    'helps' => 'Check for yes'
    );

    $form_fields['bar'] = array(
    'label' => 'Is Bar',
    'input' => 'html',
    'html' => '<label for="attachments-' . $post->ID . '-bar"> '.
        '<input type="checkbox" id="attachments-'.$post->ID . '-bar" name="attachments[' . $post->ID . '][bar]" value="1"'.( $bar ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ).' /> Yes</label>  ',
    'value' => $bar,
    'helps' => 'Check for yes'
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
```