# How do i save and retrieve custom attachment meta?

Tags: custom-field, attachments, uploads

I'm trying to save if a checkbox inside of the media uploader pop up is checked, so i can retrieve it from the front end.

I'm using this code:

```
function filter_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $foo = (bool) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'foo', true);

    $form_fields['foo'] = array(
        'label' => 'Is Foo',
        'input' => 'html',
        'html' => '<label for="attachments-'.$post->ID.'-foo"> ' . '<input type="checkbox" id="attachments-'.$post->ID.'-foo" name="attachments['.$post->ID.'][foo]" value="1"'.($foo ? ' checked="checked"' : '').' /> Yes</label>  ',
        'value' => $foo,
        'helps' => 'Check for yes'
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
```

from this question:
[How to add a checkbox element to attachments editor with example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/how-to-add-a-checkbox-element-to-attachments-editor-with-example)

I have to admit i don't completely understand how this piece of code is put together. I tried using this function to save:

```
function image_attachment_fields_to_save($post, $attachment) {  
    if( isset($attachment['imageLinksTo']) ){  
        update_post_meta($post['ID'], '_imageLinksTo', $attachment['imageLinksTo']);  
    }  
    return $post;  
} 

add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "image_attachment_fields_to_edit", null, 2); 
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "image_attachment_fields_to_save", null, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field id has to match in both function so if your field id is `foo` the when you save you need to look for that id and when you save a checkbox field its smart to remove it if not set so:

```
function image_attachment_fields_to_save($post, $attachment) {  
    if( isset($attachment['foo']) ){  
        update_post_meta($post['ID'], 'foo', $attachment['foo']);  
    }else{
         delete_post_meta($post['ID'], 'foo' );
    }
    return $post;  
}

add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "image_attachment_fields_to_save", null, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you! But... What i don't understand is how - id="attachments-'.$post->ID.'-foo" - is the same as -  update_post_meta($post['ID'], 'foo', $attachment['foo'])

Comment: And how do i call this metadata at the front end, to f.eks. check if the checkbox is checked (check check :p)

Comment: it's not, but the name of the field is the same.
to get the data you use `get_post_meta($attachment_id,'foo',true);`